# How to connect Dapp to Metamask and interact with smart contract deployed on Ropsten via Remix

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I deployed a smart contract via remix to the ropsten testnet and now I want to interact with it via website(dapp). I am creating a auction dapp. The user has to input the amount of ETH he want's to bid for the article. After the value is submitted via button click I want metamask to pop up and handle the transaction.

I got the js code for connecting to metamask from https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations

```
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
 }
else{
      console.log('MetaMask not installed!');
}

const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');

ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getAccount();
});

async function getAccount() {
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  const account = accounts[0];
  showAccount.innerHTML = account;
}
```

And it's working fine Metamask is popping up, but the part where I am stuck is how to connect the dapp to the deployed ropsten contract(deployed it via remix and it's visible on ropsten etherscan).

I tried to connect it with this js script

```
<script>
      // Initialize Web3
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
      }

      // Set Account
      web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

      // Set Contract Abi
      var contractAbi = []; // Add Your Contract ABI here!!!

      // Set Contract Address
      var contractAddress = ''; // ?????

      // Set the Contract
      var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
      ...

    </script>
```

But I don't know how to connect it to the contract deployed on ropsten.

After I have done some reading on the internet I created an infura node to connect to the contract, but I got stuck again. Do I have to connect to infura node when I am only using metamask to interact with the dapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67145/how-to-connect-web3-with-metamask/78987) on how to connect your Web3 with Metamask.

Once you are successfully connected with Metamask. You will need to put **contractABI** in

```
// Set Contract Abi
   var contractAbi = []; // Add Your Contract ABI here!!!
```

and **contractAddress** in

```
// Set Contract Address
   var contractAddress = ''; // ?????
```

Then you can initialize the `contract` object by providing **contractABI** and **contractAddress** in

```
// Set the Contract
   var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
```

This `contract` object will then allow you to interact with your deployed contracts..

Comment: How do I connect to contract deployed on ropsten testnet, I don't know how to get the contract adress url

Comment: I haven't tried this one with Metamask myself. but first make sure that your Metamask is switched to Ropsten Testnet because this is where your contract is. 
You need to first make a successful connection with Metamask. I have posted the other similar question in my answer. Once the connection is established then you are basically connected to your contract. you just need  to execute its function after initializing